# Is there a relation between abs(fft(u.^2)) and abs((fft(u)).^2

Tags: fft, frequency-spectrum, power-spectral-density

Is there a relation between

(1) abs(fft(u.^2))
(2) abs((fft(u)).^2

where u is a general variable.
I have accidentaly found that if (1) has a power law +2, (2) has a power law +1. Can someone help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a relation?

Generally no. Squaring is a highly non-linear operation and completely changes the amplitude statistics and spectrum of the original signal. A simple example: if your input consists of a few sine waves of different frequency, the output will be all positive and the spectrum will contain lines are all possible combinations of sum and difference of the original frequencies. The bandwidth will also double which in the discrete domain will often result in aliasing.

> has a power law +1

I have no idea what that means.

Comment: I mean that if for example: abs(fft(u.^2))= x^2 then abs((fft(u)).^2=x

Comment: @AshishBhigah dot means element-wise operation. So, for case 1, first of all you square all the elements of u then perform fft and abs. In case 2, you perform fft, abs then only square all the elements. 
Consider, u = [1,-2,3]
case 1, gives => [14.  7.  7.]
case 2, gives => [ 4. 19. 19.]
If I am not wrong.What does power law means?

Comment: Dear @Hilmar, thank you for your answer. I suspected it. Thank you